# Linq/lambda to get immediate parent of the matching children record(three level object)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have class definition for Topic like below with children and it can go three level deep. What I want get is the immediate parent(as a list/collection) of the item that matches. The below code will get me the result I want,but I have to use 2 steps. How can I do it in one step.

C# code.

```
      string id = 'edf23fb667f5';
       var topics = GetTopics(); //Get the data from DB with childre
       var topic = topics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Id == id)); //First level match
 var subTopic = topic?.Children.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == id); //Second level match

public class Topic
{
   public string Id;
   public string Name;
   public List<Topic> Children;
}
```

I have the sample json like below

```
[
  {
    "Id": "5174daff0f78",
    "Name": "First Level",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Id": "9ea17d89bc60",
        "Name": "Second Level",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Id": "afb2a0cd3bd9",
            "Name": "Third Level 1",
            "Children": []
          },
          {
            "Id": "edf23fb667f5",
            "Name": "Third Level 2",
            "Children": []
          },
          {
            "Id": "506b4cd4922b",
            "Name": "Third Level 3",
            "Children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: *What I want get is the immediate parent*. But you *also* want the `subtopic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string id = "edf23fb667f5";
        var topics = GetTopics();
        var subTopic = topics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Id == id))
        .Children.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

Comment: This works. The 2 step way allow to check for null. Thanks

Comment: This will error if `topics.FirstOrDefault` returns `null`.